# How to create new firebase db programmatically through API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I would like to create a separate firebase db for every client inside my firebase account. I **don't** want the client data to be a sub-branch of one single database. How do I achieve this without using the dashboard UI from firebase? I need to do it programmatically because there are many steps involved, e.g.:

1. Creation of an client administrator user
2. Creation of a predefined client database structure
3. Creation of a license for the client
4. Store information about the new client inside my license database (separate firebase db)
5. Creating separate backup script for every single client db

How do I set or get the secret of the new created database via API (programmatically)?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: We have a similar situation and the answer is there isn't a way to do it in the sense presented. You can however, separate your clients via Rules. Your clients and their data will exist in the same space - and it's doable as long as they have the same JSON structure. If their structure is different per client it can get complicated, depending on how much of a difference there is. I posted this question in google groups [One Firebase, Multiple Company Clients](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/Multiple$20Clients/firebase-talk/h9psZ58xHI8/vQxyhXJclBMJ)

Comment: Hi Jay. So you end up with one big firebase database and you have separated all companies in single sub-branches, right? Something like this: /<master-db>/client1/data

Comment: It's not so much one big database - it's a main path to get to your apps data, and then separate sub-paths to get to each clients data, as illustrated by your example. There are other ways to do it but having each 'client node' (path) distinct makes writing the rules easier. For example, when a user auth's, a Rule only enables them to access data within their own client node. An 'admin user' will only be able to view users within their own node etc. I will say that rules are a constant struggle for me it's the one thing that takes the most amount of time and effort to get right.

Answer (score 2):

As Kato answered on [your related Github question](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/106):

> There is no programmatic way to create a project. There is also a limit on the number of free projects you can create.

Comment: Hello Frank. First of all thanks for the quick answer. But what's about firebase-tools? With firebase-tools init it's possible to create new databases. My question is how to use the tools as module to create a new database?

Comment: It is possible to create a project programmatically using firebase tools

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create firebase projects, databases, apps using firebase tools.
Please refer to

[firebase tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)